# Pass arguments to Scapy's Automaton.run() method

Tags: python, scapy

I am trying to create an automaton to parse different packets with Scapy's Automaton class.

In order to do that I need to be able to pass the packet as an argument to the automaton.
One way to do so would be to pass the packet when the automaton is created:

```
my_automaton = MyAutomaton(packet)
```

This argument would be handled by the `parse_args` function overloaded in the automaton code:

```
class MyAutomaton(Automaton):
  def parse_args(self, pkt, **kargs):
    Automaton.parse_args(self, **kargs)
    self.pkt = pkt
  ... REST OF CLASS ...
```

This works nicely if I create a new automaton for each incoming packet.

But I'd like to create only one automaton and run it with different packets.
Something like:

```
my_automaton = MyAutomaton()
my_automaton.run(pkt1)
my_automaton.run(pkt2)
```

According to the documentation this should be possible ([link](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_usage.html#automata)):

```
The parse_args() method is called with arguments given at __init__() and run(). Use that to parametrize the behaviour of your automaton.
```

And by printing to console when the `parse_args` method is called I verified that it is indeed called at automaton creation and when the `run` method is called.

But I don't seem to be able to pass any argument through the `run` function, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown on the doc, you need to pass the arguments while initializing the automaton:

```
>>> TFTP_read("my_file", "192.168.1.128").run()
```

In your case that would be

```
my_automaton = MyAutomaton(pkt1)
my_automaton.run()
my_automaton2 = MyAutomaton(pkt2)
my_automaton2.run()
```

Comment: As I said in the question, creating a new automaton for each packet works for me. My doubts regard this statement in the docs: "The parse_args() method is called with arguments given at __init__() and run()", to me it looks like they are saying I could pass arguments to the run() method and handle them in the parse_args() method. But I may be understanding it wrong.

Comment: parse_args is called when you run `run()`, with the arguments provided at initialization. `run()` is only used to start the automaton. That allowed it to be started multiple times. You could always change `my_automaton.init_args` or `my_automaton.init_kargs`, before calling run() again, but that’s more of a hack.

Comment: Have a look at the source code if you want to check what I said: https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/master/scapy/automaton.py

Comment: Thank you. These last comments clarified the issue :)